# Does Xamarin support highcharts/highstock?

Tags: javascript, svg, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on asp.net MVC 5 and i am using dot net highcharts

Now i want to make an android app using Xamarin

I want to ask does it fully supports highcharts/highstock?

I have searched and read many articles but couldn't find any satisfactory answer

One link is [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39583/highchart) and other one is [this](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/does-highcharts-work-with-xamarin-phonegap-t32197/)

These 2 links have answers but not 100% satisfactory as i want to use higcharts in my mobile app as well using Xamarin

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I've used HighCharts in Android's `WebView` and iOS's `WKWebView` that was embedded in a Xamarin app... Open your mobile browser and go to HighChart's demo pages, or your own app. You of course need to make your HighChart web pages mobile size friendly...

Comment: ok, i will check this out when i started development in Xamarin

Comment: @SushiHangover can you please provide sample of high chart for xamarin Android as I am trying that but not able to include java script code inside my HTML page.Do I need to install anything for that?